# Replace Next and Previous Month by Next And previous Day in datepicker using Bootstsrap Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a jquery bootstrap datepicker inline, and I want to increment and decrement the current day
I try with this :

```
// Html Code
<div id="datepicker"></div> 

// JS Code
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    language: 'en', 
 });
$('.btn-next').on("click", function () {
    var currentDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var selectedDate= new Date(currentDate);
    // Increase current day by +1
    selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('update',selectedDate);
});

$('.btn-prev').on("click", function () {
    var currentDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var selectedDate= new Date(currentDate);
    // Decrease current day by -1
    selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() - 1);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('update',selectedDate);
});
```

But it doesn't work anymore, any idea for this operator

Comment: could you show your html code? and how you intialize your datepicker

Comment: @Frenchy I modified the post

Comment: and your input, you are using bootstrap datepicker? give a sample complete with button, in this way people could help you with a real sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert that date again which you got from datepicker just `+1` or `-1` to it and add new value inside datepicker.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  todayHighlight: true,
  language: 'en',
});
$('.btn-next').on("click", function() {
  var currentDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('update', currentDate);
});

$('.btn-prev').on("click", function() {
  var currentDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('update', currentDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-bqVeqGdJ7h/lYPq6xrPv/YGzMEb6dNxlfiTUHSgRCp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-siyOpF/pBWUPgIcQi17TLBkjvNgNQArcmwJB8YvkAgg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<button class="btn-prev">Prev</button>
<button class="btn-next">Next</button>
```